# TestNG, ITestContext - getIncludedGroups returns Null

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

There are several tests with different test groups. And I'm trying to run each of them with different set of data by using @DataProvider with ITestContext inside. I get NullPointerException. Here is my code:

```
String url = "http://google.com";
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@BeforeTest(groups={"A","B"})
public void launchOfBrowser(){
    driver.get(url);
}

@Test(dataProvider="Search", groups="A")
public void searchByUser(String author, String key) throws InterruptedException{
    System.out.println("Welcome " + author + ", your search value is: " + key);
    String enteredValue;
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(key);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    enteredValue = driver.findElement(By.name("q")).getAttribute("value");
    Assert.assertEquals(enteredValue, key);
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).clear();
}

@Test(dataProvider="Search", groups="B")
public void searchByIncognito(String key) throws InterruptedException{
    System.out.println("Your search value is: " + key);
    String enteredValue;
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(key);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    enteredValue = driver.findElement(By.name("q")).getAttribute("value");
    Assert.assertEquals(enteredValue, key);
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).clear();
}

@AfterTest(groups={"A","B"})
public void closeSessions(){
    driver.quit();
}

@DataProvider(name="Search")
public static Object[][] getDataFromDataprovider(ITestContext c){

    Object[][] groupArray = null;

    for(String group : c.getIncludedGroups()){
        if (group.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
            groupArray =  new Object[][] {
                { "Guru99", "India" },
                { "Krishna", "UK" },
                { "Bhupesh", "USA" }
            };
        }
        else{
            groupArray =  new Object[][] {
                { "India" },
                { "UK" },
                { "USA" }
            };
        }   
    }
    return groupArray;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you directly run your testng class, it will first call dataprovider which cant get groups information as groups are not available. But instead if you call this class via testng.xml, it will have groups info available with ITestContext.
- You need to call this class(class name is say 'ParameterByITestContextInDataprovider') through TestNG xml.

Below is sample xml:-

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://beust.com/testng/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="test-parameter">

  <test name="example1">

    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="A" />
        </run>
    </groups>

    <classes>
       <class
        name="com.package123.ParameterByITestContextInDataprovider" />
    </classes>

  </test>


  <test name="example2">

    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="B" />
        </run>
    </groups>

    <classes>
       <class
        name="com.package123.ParameterByITestContextInDataprovider" />
    </classes>

  </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Thanks, man. Now everything works fine. I have two more questions:

1) Does it mean that ITestContext works only with .XML? Because each method returns null, even getName()..
Could I control flow with the help of priority parameter of annotation?

2) If ITestContext is parameter of static method which is presented out side class with tests. How I can control flow in that case?

Comment: @cherevychenkosa, Yes we can do that:- Use **ItestNGMethod** instead of ITestContext:                                                                                                                                                  - Pass following argument to method **getDataFromDataprovider(ITestNGMethod m)**                                          and use **m.getGroups()** in for each loop                                              - Execute it without xml and it should work. It worked for me.

Comment: @cherevychenkosa [`ITestNGMethod`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/ITestNGMethod.html) document states **This interface is not meant to be implemented by users.**

Comment: `ITestContext` gives you the groups that are currently being run (both the included groups and excluded groups) by the runner as specified in testng.xml (or null, as discussed above, if you're running the test or test class directly) while `ITestNGMethod` gives you the groups which are annotated on the current test method that the provider is being called for.  Your provider method can actually get _both_ the `ITestContext` and `ITestNGMethod` objects as parameters at the same time.